# SQL SERVER 16 Incorrect Syntax near Generated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hi there so i have tried a couple of different variants to create at temporal table in MS SQL SERVER 2016.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3680/introduction-to-sql-server-temporal-tables/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15

[SQL Server 2016 Temporal table Throwing Incorrect Syntax for "GENERATED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498118/sql-server-2016-temporal-table-throwing-incorrect-syntax-for-generated)

However, none of them have fixed my issue that the error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 99 
>  Incorrect syntax near
>   'GENERATED'.
>  Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 104
>  Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.
>  Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 106
>  Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

still comes up.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report-New-History](
[ReportId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[SysStartTime] [DATETIME2] NOT NULL,
[SysEndTime] [DATETIME2] NOT NULL,
);
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_ReportHistory
    ON [Report-New-History];
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ReportNew_History_ID_PERIOD_COLUMNS
    ON [Report-New-History] (SysEndTime, SysStartTime, ReportId);
GO

CREATE TABLE [Report-New]
(
    [ReportId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PreviousCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,  
    SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,     
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Report
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReportId] ASC) 
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)  
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.[Report-New-History]));
```

That what i have now but it doesnt work either.

Any advice on how to make it work?

Comment: I can't replicate that specific error on SQL Server 2017; I get a completely different error. To ask a *silly* question, are you definately using SQL Server 2016? You aren't mistaking SSMS 2016 for SQL Server 2016 are you..?

Comment: You have extra columns in your history table. Is that allowed? I don't believe it is.

Comment: It isn't, @SeanBrookins (why I get a completely different error). The fact that the OP is getting the error they are suggests that they are using a version (or compatibility level) of SQL Server that doesn't support temporal tables.

Comment: Ive removed columns from the second create to save on scroll time. They are all there. Sorry I did mean SSMS i "misspoke"/ "mistyped"

Comment: That's a good point, Larnu. If Besarion isn't certain, he should check the server version of the instance he's connected to. Good catch.

Comment: Besarion, you need to have SQL server compatibility 13.0 or higher to use temporal tables. If you look at your instance and it says 12, for example, using SSMS 2016 is not sufficient to create this compatibility.

Comment: You haven't stated that you have SSMS 2016, @Besarion , I was asking if you had mistaken the version of SSMS you have for meaning the version of SQL Server. The 2 are completely unrelated, however, many (wrongly) think they are.

Comment: Yes you are correct i am using 12.0. So I cant use Temporal tables. Well that solves that

Comment: SQL Server version 12 is SQL Server 2014, @Besarion . It does not support temporal tables.

Comment: I have voted to close this as off-topic as this is no longer reproducible; the OP was simply mistaken on the version of SQL Server they are using.

Comment: Thats fine. So ill just use a Trigger instead and have a copy table.